# Значение по умолчанию при добавлении строки в таблицу в БД

Tags: sql-server, sql

Для упрощения вопроса, пусть есть таблица [item] с двумя полями [id] и [id_equal].

Поле [id] - идентификатор с автоматическим счетчиком. Как при добавлении строки по умолчанию вставить в поле [id_equal] то, что вставилось в [id]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего создать вычисляемое поле:

```
create table test([id] int identity, [id_equal] as [id])
go
insert into test default values 
select * from test
```

Comment: если оно будет редактируемым впоследствии, то не подходит. а если редактируемым не будет, то какой в нем смысл? оригинальные idшники кто-то менять собирается (это к ТС вопрос)?

Comment: Если меняться будет, тогда можно использовать триггер.

Comment: @msi, именно

Answer (score -1):

возможно есть более красивое решение. Но это работает. Только что проверял. 
P.S. проверял для MySQL

```
INSERT INTO `item` VALUES();
UPDATE `item` SET `id_equal` = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```